# TypeError: argument should be string, bytes or integer, not tuple

Tags: python

```
TypeError: argument should be string, bytes or integer, not tuple
```

I'm very new to coding and I am working on a script that should read data from two .csv files. `file_one` skipping the first three rows and `file_two` shipping the first two cols. I get the above error for the below section of code.

```
if os.path.exists(file_one_path) and os.path.exists(file_two_path):
file_one = pd.read_csv(file_one_path)
file_two = pd.read_csv(file_two_path)
try:
    assert (file_one.shape[0] == file_one.shape[0])
except AssertionError:
    print ("Please check the data provided.")
    exit()
```

*pd is pandas

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-54-e2504f2fa109>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/..., wdir='C:/Users/.....)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/.......", line 29, in <module>
    if os.path.exists(file_one_path) and os.path.exists(file_two_path):

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py", line 19, in exists
    os.stat(path)

TypeError: argument should be string, bytes or integer, not tuple
```

Comment: Hi MiguelA - it's hard to tell where this error is coming from based on the code you've given. It would help if you pasted the complete stack trace into the question.

Comment: I think that should be `file_one.shape[0] == file_two.shape[0]`. Also you don't need parens on the assert statement.

Comment: The stack trace would allow us to find out where your issue is, but the error means that you are calling a function, and one of the parameters you are assigning it with is a tuple, where it should be a string, a byte or an integer. Find out which the

Comment: Where are `file_one_path` and `file_two_path` coming from?

Comment: The problem is on line 29 of your program;  `file_one_path` and/or `file_two_path` is a tuple when it should not be.  Where do you assign to those names?  Show that code, since that is where the problem is.

Comment: `file_one_path ='C:/Users/fullPathofthefile'
  file_two_path ='C:/Users/fullpathofthefile',`
I assigned the full path of the file located on my desktop

Comment: I also used `file_one_path = str(input('Please enter the path of file one: '))
                   file_two_path = str(input('Please enter the path of file two: '))'
where I entered the full location of the files and received the same errors`

Comment: @MiguelA Edit your question to reflect the code where `file_one_path` and `file_two_path` are defined. Is the comma, quoted as part of the code in your comment, actually part of the code?  If so, then that is the error.  A comma in that location creates a tuple.

Comment: Also, are you using python 2 or python 3?  `input()` behaves _very_ differently in the two.

Comment: It was part of my code, I removed it and now I have a different error which I believe I can fix. Thank you

Comment: Reference for you: [Python Tutorial on Tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)  `a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses)`

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thank you!